# SQL Injection Exploiting Login form

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I was wondering while testing my website that is there any way that the user can fetch data from my database by making some further modification in the following query

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='admin' AND password='1' OR '1'='1';
```

provided that he knew `admin` username and used `'1'='1'` for password to hack into it.

What else can he add to echo the password on screen or find table details?

I want to do this to understand the limits the unprotected `SQL` can harm us for my presentation on SQL injection

Comment: Thats what SQL injection attack is, you need not know the password to inject query into the sql query used.

Comment: Is that the actual code in your application? Because it doesn't seem to have an input for the actual password. Where would `='1' OR '1'='1'` come from?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Don't you mean that the `' OR '1'='1';` part is the hack itself - something that attacker put into password field of your form. Then it make sense

Comment: I am aware of sql prevention techniques but i wanted to know some possible way to move to the  page www.abc.com/admin/index.php which shows content only when a particular session variable is created ,by bypassing login page.

Comment: Also password should be hashed BEFORE it is passed to a query, so the only vulnerable part would be the username. And don't forget about comments `-- --` to kill the end of the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that :

```
 ' OR '1'='1';
```

is a hack then possibilites might be endless if input is not sanitized eg:

```
' OR '1'='1'; drop table users;
```

ect.

Comment: Most server-side languages have multiple queries disabled, so this might not work.

Answer (score 1):

form injection into username and password boxes should be as follows..
z' OR 'x'= 'x.....
but attackers can use an url injection technique to fetch info from your website

Answer (score 0):

This sql query:-

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='admin' AND password='1' OR '1'='1';
```

evaluates to `SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='admin'  AND TRUE`

so it will select rows where `login column` value is **admin**. It can be used to bypass the login. It has a serious SQL injection vulnerability.

Its better to use **Prepared Statement**. The problem with **SQL injection** is, that a user input is used as **part of the SQL statement**. By using prepared statements you can force the user input to be handled as the **content of a parameter** (and not as a part of the SQL command).

Comment: `AND` has a higher precedence than `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best way to keep yourself safe from SQL injection is to use **PreparedStatement** instead of **Statement**.

Answer (score 0):

If you salt and hash the password (instead of storing it directly in the table), then the user cannot inject SQL via the password.

If you table looks like so:

```
TABLE users:
+-------+-----------+---------------------------+---------------...
| login |   salt    |         password          | other columns ...
+-------+-----------+---------------------------+---------------...
| foo42 | 231732156 | d4154b1134b511a5461efe423 |               ...
| bob69 | 765219179 | bba3ef876fe78ebacdccd87ff |               ...
+-------+-----------+---------------------------+---------------...
```

Then you can store the "password" the first time a user creates their account by generating a one-time random salt, appending it to the end of the user-submitted password, and hashing it.  Now, whenever the user tries to log in, you just recompute the hash and check it against the stored password.  This way, they can use a password like `' or '1' == '1` if they want, but your server will only use the hash (which may look like `bba3ef876fe78ebacdccd87ff`, for example)